# Ethereum vs rootstock

Tags: bitcoin, altcoin

How does ethereum compare to [rootstock](http://rootstock.io)? Except obviously that rootstock uses bitcoins exclusively.

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/what-features-are-possible-on-ethereum-than-can-never-be-implemented-with-rootst

Comment: @eth that answered my question

Comment: upvoted for the engagement